# Text Styling in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone know how to create elaborate designs in the console with text, like hashtags and dashes and such? I'm trying to integrate this into my senior project for high school and wanted to wow my teacher

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be specific. In particular, have a read through: [mcve]. In general, you will only find answers to specific questions, which often involves sharing some of your existing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a library for this like [asciimatics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciimatics), this will enable you to colour the terminal, animate it, keyboard and mouse input, it offers a lot.  If you want it to be console based then this is the way to go.

If you would like to build something from scratch then you could apply something based on terminal size using the `os` module.  For example this would fill the first line with `#`:

```
import os
a = os.get_terminal_size()
print( a.columns * "#")
```